# SQL select rows with number in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 1:N table where every entity may have asigned multiple numbers.

```
ID  Number
1  10
1  13
1  11
1  12
1  16
2  11
2  12
2  13
2  10
```

Now,I want all IDs which have for example 3 numbers in ascending sequence. I do not specify which numbers I want, I just want the SQL to return me all possible combinations it can find but the numbers **has to be in ascending sequence and the sequence must contain exactly 3 numbers**. The numbers are allways integers of any value. The numbers in result have to be next to each other (12,13,16)is not valid result.

For 3 numbers in this example it would be :
ID 1 : (10,11,12),(11,12,13)
ID 2 : (11,12,13),(10,11,13)

For 2 numbers in this example it would be:
ID 1 : (10,11),(11,12),(12,13)
ID 2 : (11,12)(12,13)

Is this possible in SQL select? Thanx

Comment: Whats the better option? Dont think selecting whole table into the app and processing it there is the right way to go

Comment: Where did the 16 for `ID` 1 go? And why is e.g. (10, 13) missing in the example for two numbers for `ID` 2? Your question seems inconsistent.

Comment: The numbers are and will be totally random. The example is just a simplification of the real problem.

Comment: The sticky bit's question still holds true. You want 3 numbers from the set, but there are more. How do you drop number 16 with example ID1? How do you pick 3 when there are more unique numbers?

Comment: You can not get result for 16 because there is no 15 and 14 so there is nothing a 16 can make a set with. I guess I should have mentioned that the numbers from the set have to be next to each other

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution whats comes close to your expected output. 
Involves using self inner joins incombination with CONCAT_WS, GROUP_CONCAT..

For group of three you use this query

**Query**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet

SELECT 
   records.ID
 , GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', records.number, ')'))
FROM ( 

  SELECT 
   DISTINCT 
       table11.ID
     , CONCAT_WS(
         ','
       , table11.Number
       , table12.Number
       , table13.Number
     ) AS number 
  FROM 
   Table1 AS table11

  INNER JOIN 
   Table1 AS table12
  ON
   table11.Number + 1 = table12.Number

  INNER JOIN 
    Table1 table13
  ON
   table12.Number + 1 = table13.Number

  ORDER BY
    table11.ID ASC
  , table11.Number ASC

) AS records 

GROUP BY 
 records.ID
```

**Result**

```
| ID | GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', records.number, ')')) |
|----|------------------------------------------------|
|  1 |                          (11,12,13),(10,11,12) |
|  2 |                          (11,12,13),(10,11,12) |
```

see demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5dfce/39

Comment: The concat will not be necessary as the output was just an example, but the inner tables are excelent. Thank you

Comment: @user3607584 np your expected results looks like you wanted comma separated groups enclosed with parentheses

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `join`.  This produces a result set with each examples of sequential numbers on a different row:

```
select id, t1.number, t2.number, t3.number
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and t2.number = t1.number + 1 join
     t t3
     on t3.id = t2.id and t3.number = t2.number + 1;
```

If you really wanted a list, you would simply do:

```
select id,
       group_concat('(', t1.number, ',', t2.number, ',', t3.number, ')') as groups
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t2.id = t1.id and t2.number = t1.number + 1 join
     t t3
     on t3.id = t2.id and t3.number = t2.number + 1
group by t1.id;
```

Comment: Yes, that is what Raymond answered without the concat part. Thank you

Comment: @user3607584 . . . Nope.  The join conditions are not correct.  The rest of that query also seems needlessly complicated.